# Solving $\cos z=i\sin z$, $z$ complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

Solving $\cos z=i\sin z$, $z$ complex number.

Well, for me is not solution because after replace $$\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=i\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
equivalently

$$2e^{-iz}=0$$

but here i dont find solution. Is fine my attempt?

Thank you

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right, indeed by $z=x+iy$ we have

$$|e^{-iz}|=|e^{-ix+y}|=|e^y||e^{-ix}|=e^y>0$$

or as an alternative pointed out by MartinR

$$e^{iz}e^{-iz}=e^0=1$$

therefore no solution exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!1

Comment: Better (IMO): $e^{-iz} e^{iz} = 1$. I would always calculate directly with complex numbers if possible, instead of resorting real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks! Indeed this is really fine. Of course this is a very useful approach, more elegant, I agree with that.